# Multiple DbContexts in a single project

Tags: entity-framework

I am working on a project using EF5 and am lost when it comes to adding a second DbContext to the project. I have created the DbContext but my migrations do not work. How do I make sure that my second DbContext (totally separate database) is set up and I can start updating the database?

Doing a "Enable-Migration" fails because a Configuration file/class already exists for my previous DbContext.

Answer (score 0):

You should split your data access libraries into separate projects.  This way you can treat each one separately, and they have no danger of conflicting with each other (so long as you call them something different).  I would also suggest making sure they are in unique namespaces.